# Need help in solving the class not found error in PHP while refactoring the code

Tags: php, oop

I have just started digging into PHP OOPs concept. For this I have created a Class and an Interface in the same file. Everything works well till this moment. Further I started refactoring my code and separated both Class and Interface to their respective files. After this I am getting below error:

> Fatal error: Interface 'TaskInterface' not found in E:\www\project\oop\Tasks.php on line 4

Below line solve that error, however I need a way to resolve it through Composer and Namespace.

```
require 'TaskInterface.php';
```

Both of the files are under same directory level.

Class Tasks: (Tasks.php)

```
use App\TaskInterface;
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
class Tasks implements TaskInterface {
 public function create()
 {
    var_dump('created');
 }
}
$obj = new Tasks();
echo $obj->create();
```

Interface Task: (TaskInterface.php)

```
namespace App;
interface TaskInterface {
 public function create();
}
```

Here is composer.json code to autoload class/interface:

```
{
"name" : "OOP",
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "project/oop/"
    }
 }
}
```

Project URL: http://localhost/project/oop/tasks.php

Directory Structure:

```
|project
|oop
  -|vendor
     -|composer (containing all auto generated files)
     -|autoload.php
  -|composer.json
  -|TaskInterface.php
  -|Tasks.php
```

Comment: How are you including/autoloading the files? You'll need to do one or the other, PHP doesn't automatically know where to look on the filesystem when you reference a class/interface name.

Comment: Do you ever load the interface? Are you using an autoloader?

Comment: @iainn and naththedeveloper I have used composer to autoload files. Please see the edited question.

Comment: Your Composer configuration is telling the autoloader to look under `project/oop/` for files in the `App` namespace, but your class and interface don't look like they're in a namespace at all.

Comment: @iainn I have declared namespace but still same error. Please see the edited question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not certain which step you're missing, but this should be a fully working example.

Assuming the following directory structure:

```
├── composer.json
├── project
│   └── oop
│       ├── TaskInterface.php
│       └── Tasks.php
└── vendor
    ├── autoload.php
```

### project/oop/TaskInterface.php

```
<?php
namespace App;

interface TaskInterface {
  public function create();
}
```

### project/oop/Tasks.php

```
<?php
namespace App;

require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php');

class Tasks implements TaskInterface {
  public function create()
  {
    var_dump('created');
  }
}

$obj = new Tasks();
echo $obj->create();
```

### composer.json

```
{
  "name" : "OOP",
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "project/oop/"
    }
 }
}
```

---

```
$ composer dump-autoload
Generating autoload files

$ php project/oop/Tasks.php
string(7) "created"
```

### The important parts

- Every file containing a class or interface definition should declare a namespace
- Deeper namespace declarations will be looked up in deeper directories underneath *project/oop/*. If you declare a class **Product** in the `App/Foo` namespace, your source file would need to be in *project/oop/Foo/Product.php*.
- When referencing a class or interface in the same namespace as the current file, you don't need a use statement
- The entry-point (in this case *Tasks.php*) *must* include the Composer autoloader
- You wouldn't normally mix a class definition and procedural code as you have done in *Tasks.php*, but there's no reason it won't work like that. More commonly, you'd have a shared "front-controller" higher up the directory structure somewhere that would include the autoloader and any other bootstrapping.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer and a very helpful explanations.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the @iainn answer, you can create a entry point (index.php) to your project with below few lines of code.

```
<?php
require_once(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');
use App\Tasks;
$obj = new Tasks();
echo $obj->create();
```

Put this file to the same level of composer.json. Don't forget to remove require_once... from Tasks.php